# Simple List Merge C# (Without Generics)

Tags: c#, merge, singly-linked-list

I have created a simple list class from scratch. This is for a class assignment that I have been working on for about a week - very new to lists. We can not use generics  so trying to research my question below has not been fruitful. Although I did get to watch 7 tutorials on youtube by BetterCoder and I found some stuff in my book but nothing with an example of "merging".

I have three classes - my node, my list, and my program. In my list class, I am working on building a Merge() method which eventually will compare the data in the two lists and merge them into an ordered list.

Right now for some reason my Merge method - which is very basic to help me understand what is happening - is not working correctly. It has both lists passed to it, and is adding the data from listTwo to listOne BUT for some reason when it's printing to the console the second Node's Data shows twice :

EX: 1 -> 2 -> 2

instead of printing the head (1), the next (2) and then the next (3) which it should be.

EX: 1 -> 2 -> 3

In the program class I have proven with a write line that (listOne.firstNode.Next.Next.Data) = 3 . Which it should be.

Can someone help me figure out if the nodes in list one aren't pointing to each other correctly or whatever is going on?

- My Merge Method must be passed both list objects (listOne and listTwo) and eventually I need to make those passed as references but I haven't figured that out quite yet and will focus on that later I suppose.

  ```
      namespace LinkedList
          {
    //This is my Node Class
              class Node
              {
                  public object Data { get; set; }

                  public Node Next { get; set; }

                  public Node(object dataValue) : this(dataValue, null) { }

                  public Node(object dataValue, Node nextNode)
                  {
                      Data = dataValue;
                      Next = nextNode;
                  }
              }



          //This is my List Class

              class List
              {
                  public Node firstNode;
                  public int count;

                  public List()
                  {
                      firstNode = null;
                  }

                  public bool Empty
                  {
                      get { return this.count == 0; }
                  }

                  public int Count
                  {
                      get { return this.count; }
                  }

                  public object Add(int index, object o)
                  {
                      if (index < 0)
                          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);

                      if (index > count)
                          index = count;

                      Node current = this.firstNode;

                      if (this.Empty || index == 0)
                      {
                          this.firstNode = new Node(o, this.firstNode);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
                              current = current.Next;

                          current.Next = new Node(o, current.Next);
                      }

                      count++;

                      return o;
                  }

                  public object Add(object o)
                  {
                      return this.Add(count, o);
                  }

                  public object Merge(List a, List b)
                  {
                      a.Add(b.firstNode.Data);

                      return a;
                  }

                  public void Print()
                  {
                      while (this.count > 0)
                      {
                          Console.Write(firstNode.Data + "->");

                          if(firstNode.Next != null)
                          firstNode.Data = firstNode.Next.Data;

                          count--;
                      }

                  }

              }


          //And here is my Program

              class Program
              {

                  static void Main(string[] args)
                  {
                      List listOne = new List();

                      List listTwo = new List();

                      listOne.Add(1);
                      listOne.Add(2);

                      listTwo.Add(3);


                      listTwo.Print();

                      Console.WriteLine("");


                      listOne.Merge(listOne, listTwo);

                      Console.WriteLine("");

                      listOne.Print();

                      //This line below shows that the data "3" from listTwo is being added to listOne in the list Merge Method
        //Console.WriteLine(listOne.firstNode.Next.Next.Data);

                      Console.ReadKey();
                  }
              }
     }
  ```

Comment: In your program main method, change this line `listOne.Merge(listOne, listTwo);` to `listOne = listOne.Merge(listOne, listTwo);`

Comment: In the Print() method, what is the purpose of `firstNode.Data = firstNode.Next.Data`?

Comment: @Paul Karam I just tried this - I am getting an error : "cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'LinkedList.List' ..are you missing a cast?  : I'm not sure what I would cast anything to..

Comment: @Andrew Morton Well I followed the videos I found on youtube and what I was understanding was that when inserting something into the list it would cause the first node to stop pointing to the next and that would make the pointer reappear ... am I getting that totally wrong?

Comment: @BrookeCobb Yeah, you need to cast it since the method returns an `object`, so it's more likely `listOne = (List)listOne.Merge(listOne, listTwo);` but anyways, this doesn't seem to be your problem. It was a fast skimming the question.

Comment: @BrookeCobb It is not normal for a print method to change the thing it is printing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actual problem in your print method

```
    public void Print()
    {
        Node node = firstNode;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(node.Data + "->");

            if (node.Next != null)
                node = node.Next;
        }
    }
```

**Alex Sikilinda** , you are right the `merge` method is incomplete.

```
        public object Merge(List a, List b)
    {
        Node bNode = b.firstNode;
        while (bNode != null)
        {
            a.Add(bNode.Data);
            bNode = bNode.Next;
        }

        return a;
    }
```

Comment: Seems that here is some point, as op is actually changing inner values in the class and messing it up

Comment: Thank you very much. I have corrected my Print method.

Comment: @BrookeCobb if you feel this is correct answer as expected then mark it .

Comment: It doesn't fix the `Merge` method though.

Comment: @Baskar John - apologies I tried to mark it up but I don't have enough reputation on the site. I received a pop up stating it's still counted though it won't show publicly. I'm still new here..

Comment: By mark it, he meant to click the correct sign near the answer to mark this one as accepted, if the answer fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it this way:

```
public void Merge(List b)
{
    Node lastNode = GetLastNode();

    if (lastNode != null)
    {
        lastNode.Next = b.firstNode;
    }
    else 
    {
        this.firstNode = b.firstNode;
    }
}

// this method is used to find the last node in current list
private Node GetLastNode()
{
    if (this.firstNode == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    Node current = this.firstNode;

    while (current.Next != null)
    {
        current = current.Next;
    }

    return current;
}
```

First of all, I changed signature of Merge from `public object Merge(List a, List b)` to `public void Merge(List b)`. Now we can use it like this:

```
listOne.Merge(listTwo);
```

This will link listOne's last element with the first element of listTwo and thus they are merged.

Now we need to change `Print` method since current version modifies the list, which shouldn't happen:

```
public void Print()
{
    Node currentNode = this.firstNode;

    while(currentNode != null)
    {
        Console.Write(currentNode.Data + ' ');
        currentNode = currentNode.Next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this example. I could apply this to a method that is passed both list objects then correct? I'm trying it now to see what happens. The literal question in my book is this : "Write a program that merges two ordered-list objects of integers into a single ordered-list object of integers. Method Merge of class ListMerge should receive references to each of the list objects to be merged and should return a reference to the merged-list object."  I have been trying to break the problem into pieces and tackle making a list, then printing, then merging, then the references..

Comment: Based from the problem's description it seems you actually shouldn't modify the list you are passing, but create a new list wich contain all values.

Comment: Okay that seems very doable. I will work on this now. Thank you very much for your guidance. I hope that other newbies like myself find this thread useful.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of assigning the data back to first node I assign the

```
 firstNode = firstNode.Next;
```

Please check the below Print Code

```
     public void Print()
    {
        while (this.count > 0)
        {
            Console.Write(firstNode.Data + "->");

            if (firstNode.Next != null)
                firstNode = firstNode.Next;

            count--;
        }

    }
```